# Simple curl with JSON data to PHP script yields empty $_POST

Tags: php, curl, post

I'm executing the following curl command

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"x":"1","y":"2"}' http://localhost/test.php
```

to a PHP script that looks like

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

As output I get:

```
array(0) {
}
string(17) "{"x":"1","y":"2"}"
```

In short `$_POST` is empty but the data is kind of there. I guess I could encode the string t JSON but I would prefer to know what's going on. After some online search I can exclude the following issues:

- I'm on Ubuntu, so I shouldn't have issues with single and double quotes in the `curl` command.
- I've checked my `php.ini` and `enable_post_data_reading` is enabled and `post_max_size = 8M` (and not accidentally set to 0, for example). Also confirmed via `phpinfo()`.

**UPDATE:** As the commenters pointed rightly out, I had simply the wrong expectations that I cat the JSON parameter string automatically as an $_POST array. Not to change my existing code, I followed the post linked above as related to my questions. I added the line:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

And now it works.

Comment: JSON request bodies are read from `php://input` only. `$_POST` is only populated by `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request data. I'll find a link for you with more detail

Comment: You'll want to use json_decode() as well to read the php://input contents as an object/array